# Remove state from a reactjs component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react script which does work fine. However I am learning react and a peer mentioned this to me:-

> An improvement would be to create another component that renders from
>   props. state is usually frowned upon unless needed, state is usually
>   held at root of a group with its components using props.  more props
>   == good.

I am struggling to fully grasp his comments and cannot find anything concise on google to rewrite this code. Can any one help rewriting this in a more `reactjs` way?

```
var MachineInfo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: []
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {

            this.setState({
                data: result
            });


        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function() {

        var createItem = function(item) {
            return <p>{item.Id} {item.Key} {item.Value} </p>;
        };

        return <div>{this.state.data.map(createItem)}</div>;

    }
});

React.render(
  <MachineInfo source="/ajax/namevalues/2" />,
  document.getElementById('reactdiv')
);
```

This the json I am retrieving

```
[
    {"Id":5,"Key":"Temp","Value":"160"},
    {"Id":6,"Key":"Pressure","Value":"Light"},
    {"Id":7,"Key":"Time","Value":"Pre 10 Press 20"},
    {"Id":8,"Key":"Release","Value":"Warm"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another component like `MachineInfoItem` and pass the json which will render using the props like below.

```
var MachineInfo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: []
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {

            this.setState({
                data: result
            });


        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function() {

        var createMachineInfoItems = function(info) {
            return <MachineInfoItem info={info} />
        };

        return <div>
          {this.state.data.map(createMachineInfoItems)}
        </div>;

    }
});

var MachineInfoItem = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <p>
      {this.props.info.Id}
      {this.props.info.Key}
      {this.props.info.Value}
    </p>
  }
});

React.render(
  <MachineInfo source="/ajax/namevalues/2" />,
  document.getElementById('reactdiv')
);
```

[Thinking in React](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html) is an excellent blog post which explains this.

Comment: Ah I see now from the code, its ok to populate the returned json into state. This is correct. His comments are regarding the rendering of the list of objects. i.e. create another component.

Comment: Have marked this as the answer as it makes sense. I have however also posted a slightly more refined instance where I have three components, one for getting state, one for the header, one for the items

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer to @Deepak for showing me what I needed to know. The code I ended up using was:-

```
var MachineInfo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: []
        };
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        $.get(this.props.source, function(result) {
            this.setState({
                data: result
            });
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function() {
        return  <MachineInfoHeader data={this.state.data} />       
    }
});

var MachineInfoHeader = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var createMachineInfoItems = function(info) {
            return <MachineInfoItem info={info} />
        };
        return <div>{this.props.data.map(createMachineInfoItems)}</div>
    }
});

var MachineInfoItem = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <p>
            {this.props.info.Id}
            {this.props.info.Key}
            {this.props.info.Value}
        </p>
    }
});

React.render(
  <MachineInfo source="/ajax/namevalues/2" />,
  document.getElementById('reactdiv')
);
```

Comment: To downvoter please can you indicate why you downvoted? I accepted deepaks answer and gave him a +1 as he got me in the right direction. My refinement is going to help people in the future.